# Why we use java persistence in our program rather than jdbc connection

Tags: java, persistence

What is the difference between data persistence and direct data access through jdbc?

I search this on internet many times. but I learned how to program using persistence framework. I can't understand how this differs from formal data access. Is it have any advantage rather than code simplicity?

Comment: By persistence you mean an ORM framework like Hibernate or another framework on top of JDBC like Spring JDBC, right?

Comment: persistence frameworks like hibernate helps you to map your relational data to java object model(simple pojos) which otherwise you have to code yourself using JDBC data access.

Comment: And tools such as Eclipse have wizards to generate classes from tables etc.

Comment: ok.. i know it.. what is advantage rather than ORM mapping

Answer (score 0):

If you Persist data,

number of **database calls** will get reduced.

In `ORM` if you want to change your database you **no need to change the code,** It's just a configuration change rather than code change.  But if you use `JDBC` you need to change the classes and `re-compile` and `re-deploy` which is an overhead. And `ORM` supports nearly `23 databases`. Likewise there are many advantages compare to typical `JDBC calls`. There are many concepts in many ORM frameworks such as

```
       eagerly loading 
       lazy loading 
       Pagination support
       annotation support
```

In `JDBC` all `Exceptions` are `checked exceptions`, so we must write code in `try`, `catch` and throws, but if you use `hibernate` as your `ORM` tool, we have `Un-checked exceptions`.

Answer (score 0):

Using JPA and some of its implementations like Hibernate will let you eliminate SQL statements (with eg. HQL or Criteria API which are independent on dbms). SQL statements might be database dependent. JPA allows you then even change the database completely by simple dialect change. So your application can run on different databases without needs of having multiple handlers for every database.

Of course such frameworks provides many features like cashing or dirty checkings when your data became persistent when you eg. simply change property on your model (aka you don't have to still explicitly call save or DAO to persist data when your in session).

Also you don't need to worry about sql injections etc..

But basically, more complex your application is, the need of such framework will became necessary. With simple apps you don't need ultimate frameworks :)